# fine grain sudo permission not working

Tags: sudo

I have make a configuration to `sudo` so that I can run a command without password, but only when I am in a specific group. However it is still asking for a password.

## I try it out

```bsh
#↳ sudo --group docker-user -s
#↳ sudo -k #drop sudo credentials
#↳ groups
docker-user sudo …
#↳ sudo --group docker /usr/bin/docker images
[sudo] password for bob
```

I am not expecting a password. The `docker.sudo` was meant to allow group `docker-user`, to run `docker` as group `docker`, with no password.

What have I done wrong? What is stopping it from working.

---

## Let us look at the configuration

```bsh
#↳ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/docker.sudo
Cmnd_Alias DOCKER = /usr/bin/docker
%docker-user ALL = (:docker) NOPASSWD : DOCKER

#↳ sudo cat /etc/sudoers #comments removed
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

---

## More tests

```bsh
#↳ groups
docker_user sudo …
#↳ sudo -ll
Matching Defaults entries for richard on delor-1:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User richard may run the following commands on delor-1:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    RunAsGroups: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL
```

Comment: If you look at the output of `sudo -ll`, do you confirm that the rule is correctly seen?

Comment: @einfeyn496 I don't see anything. I have added this test to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand upon the answer by @ctrl-alt-delor, the `sudoers` `man` page mentions the processing rules for the auxiliary rules found in `/etc/sudoers.d`, under the section `Including other files from within sudoers` (`sudo` version `1.9.1`)

> sudo will suspend processing of the current file and read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’ character to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files.

However, the first sentence of this section of the manual mentions that a machine local `sudoers` file in `/etc/sudoers.local` (containing a `.`) can be included directly via `@include /etc/sudoers.local`, which leads me to believe that the `.` is *only* problematic for those files included via `@includedir`.
So, I would suspect that if the original `/etc/sudoers` file had the following

```
@include /etc/sudoers.d/docker.sudo
```

the problem would not have been present (but of course the point of the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory is to use `@includedir`...)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem: For some reason if the auxiliary file in (`/etc/sudoers.d`) contains a dot in its name, then it is **not** included.

## The solution

```bsh
(
  cd /etc/sudoers.d
  sudo mv docker.sudo docker_sudo
)
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting! You might consider adding the reason mentioned in the `man` page: `sudo will suspend processing of the current file and read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’ character to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files.`